# Chrome renders fonts of certain colour thinner

Tags: css, google-chrome

I am having some trouble getting the thickness of a font to appear the same across multiple browsers. 
See the following example. If you view it in Firefox you'll notice the magenta text appears the same thickness as the white text. However, if you view it in Chrome the pink is much thinner and harder to read.

https://jsfiddle.net/9a8omhnr/

**HTML**

```
<div class="container">
  <ul>
    <li class="active"><a href="#">Nav Item One</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Nav Item Two</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Nav Item Three</a></li>
    <li class="active green"><a href="#">Nav Item Four</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.container {
  background-color: #000;
}
ul {
  display: flex;
  list-style: none;
}
ul li {
  padding: 2rem .5rem;
}
a {
  text-decoration: none;
  font-family: "Montserrat", Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-weight: 300;
  font-size: 0.8rem;
  color: #fff;
}
.active a {
  color: #ef1864;
}
```

If I increase the font-weight it doesn't solve the issue because it also increases the weighting in FF, not just Chrome, and therefore leaves the text too thick in Firefox.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done with media queries

CSS:

```
/* Chrome only: */
  @media all and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:0) 
 and (min-resolution: .001dpcm) { 
  a {
       text-decoration: none;
       font-family: "Montserrat", Helvetica, sans-serif;
       font-weight: 400;
       font-size: 0.8rem;
       color: #fff;
    }
  }
```